# Add Special Characters in Editor

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor source view I wrote `Ji&#345;&iacute;` for `Jiří` and save in mysql db it looked fine on browser but when I open in edit view but without any change save & recheck browser shows `Ji?í` I am using

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
do I need to specify another character-set (UTF-16?) in the  tag.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: I follow [HOW TO:Produce UTF-8](http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=403) 
 my related point was:

- Ensure your database (if you are using one) is set to accept UTF-8 or
  Unicode (UCS-2) characters.